# Dart - How do I know if the data is JSONArray or JSONObject

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
void getOrders(Session session, Function listener
    /*(List list,String error)*/) async {
  Map data = {
    "nabil": session.nabil,
    "username": session.username,
    config.Method.key: config.Method.getMyOrdrs
  };
  try {
    var response =
        await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(config.Server.url), body: data);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map d = json.decode(response.body);
      List lst;
      print(d);
      print("_---------_");
      if (d.containsKey(config.Param.data)&&d[config.Param.data].containsKey(config.Param.error)) {
        listener(null, d[config.Param.data][config.Param.error]);
      } else {
        //todo data
        lst = d[config.Param.data];
        listener(lst, null);
      }
    } else {
      listener(null, "not_internet");
      print(response.body);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    listener(null, "not_internet");
    print("getOrders");
    print(e);
  }
}
```

## mydata:

some time:
like this:

```json
{data: {error: session-expired}}
```

other time:

```json
{data: [{id: 1,tech: 7203, price: 75},{id: 2,tech: 7205, price: 50},{id: 3,tech: 7208, price: 85}]}
```

## Error:

> NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List' has no instance method 'containsKey'.

## How do I know if the data is JSONArray or JSONObject?

Answer (score 0):

## OK Thanks Finally I got it

```dart
void getOrders(Session session, Function listener
    /*(List list,String error)*/) async {
  Map data = {
    "nabil": session.nabil,
    "username": session.username,
    config.Method.key: config.Method.getMyOrdrs
  };
  try {
    var response =
        await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(config.Server.url), body: data);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map d = json.decode(response.body);
      List lst;
      if (d.containsKey(config.Param.data)){
        if(d[config.Param.data] is List){
          lst=d[config.Param.data];
        }else if(d[config.Param.data] is Map){
          d=d[config.Param.data];
        }
      }

      if (lst ==null && d.containsKey(config.Param.error)) {
        listener(null, d[config.Param.error]);
      } else {
        //todo data
        lst = d[config.Param.data];
        listener(lst, null);
      }
    } else {
      listener(null, "not_internet");
      print(response.body);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    listener(null, "not_internet");
    print("getOrders");
    print(e);
  }
}
```